# How to simply populate a dict in Python3.2 from a text file which has only string contents?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-3.x

How to simply populate a dict in Python 3.2 from a text file which has only string contents?

I am new to Python and I am trying to build a dictionary from a text file that contains only two columns as follows:

```
First_column        second_column
katab           perfective active 
kutib                 perfective passive 
?aktub            imperfective active 
?uktab           imperfective passive 
ka:tib               participle active 
maktu:b         participle passive
The text file contains thousands of lines.
```

1.I want the words under first_column as “keys” and the words under second_coloumn as “values”, e.g.

```
dict = {‘katab’ : ‘perfective_active’, ‘kutib’ : ‘perfective_passive’}
```

Please note that the text file contains a lot of formatting and escape characters such as ‘’, ‘\n’ and ‘\t’. So I don’t want these characters to show up in the dict.

1. How can I write the generated dict into a file and later import it into Python shell and search for a given key?

This is the code  that prints to the text file:

```
        import sys
        sys.stdout = open("/home/mohammed/seminar/awzan", "a")
        print(perfective_active+"\t perfective_active \n")
        print(perfective_passive+"\t perfective_passive \n")
        print(imperfective_active+"\t imperfective_active \n")
        print(imperfective_passive+"\t imperfective_passive \n")
        print(participle_active+"\t participle_active \n")
        print(participle_passive+"\t participle_passive\n")
        sys.stdout.close()
```

I really appreciate your kind help!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  Reading in the file? splitting the lines? stripping the white space? making the dictionary?  Show us what you have tried ;)

Comment: I tried using slicing the columns, but it did not work for me. I made many google and stackoverflow searches, but most of the posts show how to populate a dictionary with int as key and str as values.

Comment: the key can be _any_ hashable object

Comment: @tcaswell      I have provided the code above. I am using Python3.2. Can you help me again?

Comment: What is wrong with the answers already provided?

Comment: @tcaswell      It keeps throwing errors.
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 0; 2 is required

Answer (score 1):

To read the dictionary from a disk file:

```
with open('inputfile.txt') as infile:
    d = dict(x.split(None, 1) for x in infile if x.strip())
```

To write the dictionary to a disk file:

```
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(' '.join(x) for x in d.iteritems()))
```

To search for a particular value:

```
stuff = d['bother']
```

Comment: @ Rob,         Thank you for your kind help, but when I type the above code in Python interpreter, it generates the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 2, in <module>
    d = dict(x.split(None, 1) for x in infile)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #1 has length 0; 2 is required

Comment: I suspect that your input file has at least one blank line it. I'll update my answer to account for that.

Comment: Yep. Those lines alternate dictionary lines with blank lines.

Comment: @ Rob, Thank you for such a kind attention to my problem. I have provided the whole code above in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the way to split the line.

```
>>> 'katab           perfective active'.split(None, 1)
['katab', 'perfective active']
```

store the split line to dict

```
mydict = {}
for line in ifile:
    mydict.update(line.split(None, 1))
```

store the dict to file

try python pickle or cpickle module

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html